# mac terminal computer name is garbled

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

When I use terminal enter zsh, my computer name is garbled, n3-85-8 instead MacBook-Pro. Sometime so as the bash. Do anyone know why? And how to fix it.[image]

Comment: I suspect it's getting the name from reverse DNS of its IP, instead of the computer's configuration. Check your `PS1` environment variable.

Comment: How to check `PS1`, I use `vim ~/.bash_profile` and  I do not set any `PS1`. Also when I use `echo $PS1`, result is `\h:\W \u\$`. Is this right?

Comment: `zsh` doesn't use `.bash_profile` -- only `bash` uses it. Read the `zsh` documentation to find out what startup files it loads.

Comment: My bash sometime have this problem also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two effects happening here:

- Bash only reads the hostname (as displayed in the prompt) once at shell startup, which means you only see the change when you start a new shell, not when your hostname changes.
- macOS by default changes its own hostname based on the network configuration

You can configure your computer not to change its hostname (see for example [this question](https://superuser.com/q/49891/155540)).  Or, you can configure bash to use the computer's persistent `LocalHostName` in the prompt.  This value does not change when you connect to a different network.

You can edit your `~/.bashrc` (or related file) to have a line like:

```
PS1=$(scutil --get LocalHostName)':\W \u\$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Grisha's excellent answer, there are several different host names.  Often the same, but may vary to accommodate different naming constraints.  The `whatami` function (below) can help you choose which one you want in your `PS1` prompt.

Here's a Bash function to help assess the different names.

```bash
function whatami {
    local cn=$(scutil --get ComputerName)
    local lhn=$(scutil --get LocalHostName)
    local hn=$(scutil --get HostName)
    local nbn=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :NetBIOSName" /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist)
    printf '\e[1mComputerName\e[0m: '"$cn"'\n'
    printf '\e[1mLocalHostName\e[0m (Bonjour): '"$lhn"'\n'
    printf '\e[1mHostName\e[0m: '"$hn"'\n'
    printf '\e[1mNetBIOSName\e[0m (SMB): '"$nbn"'\n'
    printf '\e[1mIP Address\e[0m: '
    for x in $(ifconfig -l); do ipconfig getifaddr $x; done
}
```